# VBA CODE to create a formula in excel

Tags: excel

each time i enter a value to A1 should copy the value  automatically to cell B1 and this value should be stored in Cell B1 next time c1 next time d1 etc
source cell will be same but destination will adding 1 cell each

Comment: You can keep asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518337/updating-a-value-of-destination-cell-based-on-entry-cell) (and [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538857/excel-adding-value-by-using-vba-code-to-destination-cell-using-same-source-cell)) but you unlikely to receive an adequate answer until you show some original effort.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, V As Variant, N As Long
    Set r = Intersect(Range("A1"), Target)
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    V = r(1).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Cells(1, N + 1).Value = V
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The first entry to **A1** will be copied to **B1**.
The second entry to **A1** will be copied to **C1**, etc.

Comment: thank you so much you told the proper solution yesterday whole day i was searching for this

Comment: can i start the destination from B10

Comment: source cell will be same A1